# Jquery autocomplete: how to prevent events from firing

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Autocomplete events such as Search/Select are firing for keyboard keys like 'Home', 'End', 'Shift'.

I saw these are not firing for examples on demo site
Ex: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote.html

Please let me know how to block Search/Select events for certain keyboard events.

I think this is default behavior, but it is not working in my case.

Comment: what code are you using? Giving us a working example doesn't let us see the problem ;P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the events are firing for you but not on the demo, maybe check your version of jquery UI?

In order to block these events for certain keys you can just return false.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   search: function(event, ui) { 
     if(event.keyCode === 36) {
       // HOME key pressed
       return false;
     }
   }
});
```

See the 'events' tab [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can save the last text into a var and when fire your event check if the text has been changed.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
    search: function(event, ui) {
        if($('.selector').val() === lastText) {
            return false;
        }
        // do what do you want

        lastText = $('.selector').val();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
$( "#selectorid" ).autocomplete({
    search: function(event, ui) {
        $.lastText = $('#selectorid').val();
    }
});


$('#selectorid').keypress(function (e) {
if ($(this).val() == $.lastText) return;
});
```